# Как убрать отталкивание между объектами

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-android

Достаточно банальный, но трудный способ для понятие МНЕ. У меня есть объект Enemy, который следует постоянно за объектом Player, постоянно следуя за обновленными координатами Player. И меня не устраивает что когда оба объекта сталкиваются, то один может передвинуть другой объект. Как мне это можно отключить?